# How to select link during ROAuth step in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio, roauth

Sorry for asking a newbie question. I'm trying to do R sentiment analysis in RStudio. I could get the ROAuth script to work, but during this phase:

```
To enable the connection, please direct your web browser to: 
http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=HZ6dfylyLYN6yk1WArBsM7fjkDHEByZqhFKiSEYPzg
When complete, record the PIN given to you and provide it here:
```

I'm unable to click the link or select it with my mouse (and don't feel like manually typing in that URL in a web browser). I therefore am not able to use this script in RStudio, I have to go back to regular R. Is there some specific thing I can do to be able to click this link?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Found the solution here: http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/problems/4226-rstudio-and-roauth-handshake  it turns out all you have to do is download the newest daily version